# Touch tablet: prevent touchmove/touchstart without lag time

Tags: javascript, event-handling, touch, blackberry-playbook

How do I prevent the touchmove (touchstart?) action on a Blackberry tablet? For example, the user must not be allowed to zoom in on an image or form/button. I have tried

```
<img src= "image.jpg" ontouchstart="event.preventDefault();">
```

And also (both within and outside $(document).ready )

```
document.body.addEventListener('touchstart', function(e){ e.preventDefault(); });
```

These sort of seem to work, but not quite. When the page first loads, there is sometimes a lag time where I can zoom in. Not always, but enough for it to be a problem.

Is there a way to prevent this lagtime - or a nice way to prevent the page from displaying until I know preventDefault has been "activated"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed this header- That did the trick.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
```